# Mock context provider

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I am trying to test a component that uses context from a provider component.

```tsx
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from 'material-ui-pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
render((
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <App />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I've tried setting the context this way, but it is still complaining that context utils is not found.
AppTest

```
it('renders App Component', () => {
    const context = { utils: DateFnsUtils };

    const wrapper = shallow(<App/>, { context });

    expect(wrapper.find(App)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Error: Uncaught [Error: Can not find utils in context. You either a) forgot to wrap your component tree in MuiPickersUtilsProvider; or b) mixed named and direct file imports.  Recommendation: use named imports from the module index.

Answer (score 2):

I am the maintainer of `material-ui-pickers`.

Really, as @estus said it's required to wrap the component tree in `MuiPickersUtilsProvider`. So I suggest to create your own wrapper outside the shallow, which will render any components with context. Example

```
const renderWithContext = (renderedNode) => render(
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    {renderedNode}
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
)
```

And then in your tests

```
renderWithContext(<App />)
```

Answer (score 1):

Enzyme `context` option and `setContext` method are for [legacy context](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html).

Context API is supposed to be mocked the same way it's used in production. Considering that `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` uses context API internally, it's:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <App />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
);
```

Where `DateFnsUtils` can be either real or mocked value.

It's preferable to mock all irrelevant units in isolated unit tests, including third-party modules. This way `MuiPickersUtilsProvider` wouldn't be needed.